# Prove or disprove If $\{u_1, u_2, u_3,u_4,u_5 \}$ form basis in $\mathbb{R}^5 $ and $V$ is 2-d subspace then show that V has basis from $\mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> I have a doubt. If $\{u_1, u_2, u_3,u_4,u_5 \}$ form basis in $\mathbb{R}^5 $ and $V$ is 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ then show that V has basis of 2 elements from given basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the source of this question ? Have you translated from another language ?

Comment: I don't think this is even true. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, consider the ordinary basis $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$, and the subspace $V = \{(x,y) : x = y\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$. Then, none of the basis elements even belong to $V$, so they cannot form a basis of $V$. Every basis can be extended to a basis of the overlying space, but every basis of the overlying space may not necessarily be contractible to span a given space.

Comment: Do you mean that $V$ is spanned solely by only two vectors of the set $A={u_i, i=1...5}$ ? If it is, then I think this is not correct.

Comment: thank you sir, got it..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, this statement is false in general. I will give you this counter-example:

If $u_1=(1,0,0,0,0),\; u_2=(0,1,0,0,0),\; u_3=(0,0,1,0,0),\;\ldots$ and $V=\{(a,a,b,b,b):a,b\in\mathbb{R} \}$. It is clear that for every member of the basis: $u_i \notin V$. Therefore, it is impossible for any pair of the original basis vectors to span $V$.